# Boas práticas com requisições XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Quando faço uma requisição via `AJAX` e eu desejo "montar" o `HTML` baseado em dados vindos de um `banco`, é errado (em termos de "boas práticas") já retornar o `HTML` na própria requisição?

Ou é melhor (como faço atualmente) retornar os dados em `JSON`e utilizar um **template engine em javascript** para processar esses dados para o `DOM`?

(exemplo: **underscore.js**)

Estou perguntando isso o porque eu vi que o **Facebook**, em algumas requisições `XHR`, retorna o HTML já na própria resposta da requisição. (e daí surge aquela pergunta na cabeça: "Se o Facebook fez, é porque está certo?")

Comment: Eu acho que isso varia muito de programador pra programador e não muito de boas práticas

Comment: Eu nunca ligo para boas práticas, na verdade essa *tag* já foi removida algumas vezes e deveria até ir para a lista negra. Ela não tem significado algum, ainda mais escrita errada. Boa prática é fazer aquilo que é o certo naquela situação específica. Sem saber a situações específica qualquer indicação de "boa prática" está errada. E o maior problema é que as pessoas interpretam elas como algo a fazer sempre. Neste caso, quem nem é específico, eu diria que você deve trafegar dados. Se existe algum motivo para na sua composição existirem *tags* HTML, faça.

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas se dá para responder sem incorrer em opinião, se há algum motivo real para escolher um ou outro.

Comment: @Marcelo, O problema de "variar de programador pra programador" é que nunca se tem um padrão (isso no `PHP`, pode crer, é um problema mui grande!)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, mas isso infelizmente é em todos ambientes de programação e etc... Por exemplo ao programar um `CLP`, `microprocessador`, vc tbm não tem um padrão bem definido, a sua programação vai depender do que os produtores daquele `CI` decidiram adotar ao montar a arquitetura do mesmo... isso vai do nível mais baixo da programação até o nível mais alto

Comment: As únicas boas práticas que me ocorrem são não usar de forma síncrona e não fazer _parse_ do retorno com `eval`.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, então podemos dizer grosseiramente que os "padrões de projeto" servem apenas para diminuir o número de gambiarras? Porque realmente sempre temos o problema de algo ficar fora do padrão (mesmo que não sejam um padrão de projeto, mas o padrão aplicado àquela aplicação específica)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters "eu" diria que sim, depende do projeto, da sua necessidade, das "boas praticas da sua empresa".... mas como o @bigown disse, é difícil responder `sem incorrer em opinião`, tanto em relação a boas praticas, quanto ao próprio termo do que vem a ser uma boa prática

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já apontado por outros usuários nos comentários acima, não existem "boas práticas" a não ser em relação ao contexto específico de cada aplicação. Portanto a resposta é **sim** e **não**.

### Não, não é errado retornar o HTML diretamente

O objeto que faz a requisição foi criado para se obter XML, mas na verdade pode retornar qualquer coisa, incluindo HTML. Não há nenhum problema em fazer isso se fizer sentido dentro da sua aplicação. Por exemplo, se boa parte do HTML da sua aplicação é gerado dinamicamente no servidor, é coerente gerar também o que é obtido por requisições AJAX.

### Sim, é errado retornar o HTML diretamente

Se a sua aplicação é fortemente baseada numa engine de templates rodando do lado do cliente, não faz sentido deixar de usá-la numa situação específica, a não ser que você tenha um bom motivo para fazer isso. Ou seja, é errado retornar HTML se isso não estiver de acordo com os padrões da sua aplicação.

Comment: No caso do facebook, eles retornam o `JSON`, sendo que uma das proriedades desse JSON é uma HTML. tipo: `{_id : 1, content: "<div>text</div>"}`. Então, eles caem tanto no **sim** como no **não**

Comment: Pra você ver como são subjetivas essas "boas práticas". Provavelmente eles têm uma razão para fazer isso.